# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the Indicator Applet?

Tags: indicator, shortcut-keys, twitter

How can I get here using keyboard shortcuts?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and arrow keys, as os of 12.04. No direct shortcut thay I know of.