# Indicator Applet keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, indicator, gnome-panel

I am using gnome classic on Ubuntu 12.04 and want to use a keyboard shortcut for accessing the Indicator Applet stuff in the upper right (mail, wifi, sound, time, users, etc.).

I read through [a discussion forum](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-applet/+bug/334544) from 2010 about creating such a shortcut, and I've found answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13137/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-the-indicator-applet) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86477/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-the-indicator-area), but neither seems to work anymore.

I was able to figure out the upper left ("Applications" and "Places"), which is listed as "Show the activities overview" in the keyboard shortcuts sections of the system settings, but I can't find out how to do the same for the material in the upper right.

(Also, is there a way to set it so that it will toggle - i.e. if I have the shortcut set to the "Windows" key, one press will access the menu, and a second will cause it to escape, the way ESC does now?)

Any help is greatly appreciated.